# Integer inequality: $x + y +z> a + b + c$ does not imply $xyz > abc$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, arithmetic

Prove by contradiction that for any integers $x,y,z,a,b,c$ greater than $0$ such that $x+y>a+b$, it is not implied that $x\cdot y\cdot z>a\cdot b\cdot c$?

Obviously this statement is true. Consider $9+1+1>3+2+2; 9<12$. But I cannot seem to prove it without falling back to examples. Also, would the outcome of the statement be different if I required that all integers be greater than $1$? If so, how do i go about formalizing that thought?

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking - there is no restriction on $z$ and $c$ at all.

Comment: Sorry about that. The edit clears it up.

Answer (score 1):

One example is sufficient to show that the implication is not true.  You probably mean $x + y + z \gt a+b+c \not \implies xyz \gt abc$.  For an example with all numbers greater than $1$, you again want a large disparity on the left and small one on the right.  For example $9+2+2 \gt 4+4+4, 36 \lt 64$

Comment: Is there no way to show the implication is not true without examples?

Comment: What you are trying to prove is that there exist $a,b,c,x,y,z$ such that ..., so an example is an easy way.  There are times you prove something exists without an example (think the intermediate value theorem) but I don't see an easy way here.

Comment: I am very certain that it is quite possible to create a formula where you plug in your choice for $x$ and it gives you $y, z, a, b, c$ such that $x + y + z > a + b + c$ yet $xyz \leq abc$. But at the moment I can't come up with such a formula.

Comment: @RobertSoupe:  an easy one is to take $a=x$ and let $b,c,y,z$ do all the work, like $b=10,c=1,y=z=4$, but that is in the spirit of an example that OP doesn't like.

Comment: @RossMillikan The formula needs to be such that whatever value of $x$ one chooses, the result contradicts $xyz > abc$. Then, "the reader may work out examples if he so chooses."

Answer (score 1):

Examples can be quite healthy, guarding against excessive abstraction. But in some cases, and this may or may not be one of them, what's needed is a way to create infinitely many examples. How about this? [various failed attempts omitted here]

**EDIT**: Okay, I think I've got it now. Choose a number $n$ with at least four distinct prime factors. Now choose six nontrivial divisors (neither 1 nor the number itself) of that number and label them $x, y, z, a, b, c$ such that $x + y + z > a + b + c$ yet $xyz = abc$. Now reassign $x := x - 1$, so now $x \geq 1$ and therefore the inequality $x + y + z > a + b + c$ still holds but now $xyz < abc$. A similar adjustment can be made so as to obtain $xyz > abc$.

Comment: In your edit, why do you state that 4ab< abc? c=2; abc = 2ab<4ab.

Comment: I've made a mistake somewhere along the way. Quite a deceptively simple question you've posed. I might have to table this for tonight and come back fresh to it tomorrow.